# Get div items beside each other for printing

Tags: javascript, printing

I have two divs, one for names and the other for last Names. When I try to print them it is working fine but the problem is that Names and last names are not placed beside each other. How can I make Names and Last Names appear beside each other?
What happens is that I get all names in length line and after I get all last names in length line under all names.
my code:

```
var Name = document.getElementById("divNames").innerHTML;
var LastName = document.getElementById("divLastNames").innerHTML;

 myWindow.document.write(Name + " " + LastName);
myWindow.document.close();
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
myWindow.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make them `display: inline-block;` somehow. You could either do this with an external CSS file, like this:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Of course this will affect all `div`s on the page, so you'll probably want to add a class or id to each element.

Or you could set the style directly on the elements:

```
Name.style.display = 'inline-block';
LastName.style.display = 'inline-block';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSS Media query that will only change the divs to appear next to each other when printing:

```
@media print {
  #divNames{display:inline-block;}
  #divLastNames{display:inline-block;}
}
```